# Splitting URL in three parts in htaccess - regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to split any URL that would show up on my website into three parts:

1. Language (optional)
2. Hierarchical structure of the page (parents)
3. Current page

Right now I operate with 1 and 3 but I need to develop a way to allow for the pages to have the same names if they have different parents and therefore full URL is unique.

Here are the types of URL I may have:

```
(nothing)
en
en/test
en/parent/test
test
parent/test
ggparent/gparent/parent/test
```

I thought about extending my current directive:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:([a-z]{2})(?=\/))?.*(?:\/([\w\-\,\+]+))$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
```

to the following:

`(?:([a-z]{2})(?=\/))?(.*)\/([^\/]*)?$`

Which then I could translate to `index.php?lang=$1&tree=$2&page=$3` but the difficulty I have is that the second capturing group captures the slash from the beginning.

I believe I can't (based on my search so far) dynamically have all the strings between slashes to be returned and make the last one to always be first, without repeating the same regex. I thought I would capture anything between language and current page and process the tree in PHP.

However my current regex has some problems and I can't figure them out:

1. If language is on its own, it doesn't get captured
2. The second group captures the slash betwen language and the tree

Link to Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/ecHBQT/1

Comment: Would this help? [`^([a-z]{2}(?=$|\/))?\/?((?:[^\r\n\/]+\/)*)(\w*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/oVUy4h/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This likely does it: Split the URL by slash into lang, tree, and page at the proper place, with all three parts possibly empty:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}\b)?\/?(?:\/?(.+)\/)?(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&tree=$2&page=$3 [L,NC]
```

Testcase in JavaScript using this regex:

```js
const regex = /^([a-z]{2}\b)?\/?(?:\/?(.+)\/)?(.*)$/;
[
  '',
  'en',
  'en/test',
  'en/parent/test',
  'test',
  'parent/test',
  'ggparent/gparent/parent/test'
].forEach(str => {
  let rewritten = str.replace(regex, '/index.php?lang=$1&tree=$2&page=$3');
  console.log('"' + str + '" ==>', rewritten);
})
```

Output:

```
"" ==> /index.php?lang=&tree=&page=
"en" ==> /index.php?lang=en&tree=&page=
"en/test" ==> /index.php?lang=en&tree=&page=test
"en/parent/test" ==> /index.php?lang=en&tree=parent&page=test
"test" ==> /index.php?lang=&tree=&page=test
"parent/test" ==> /index.php?lang=&tree=parent&page=test
"ggparent/gparent/parent/test" ==> /index.php?lang=&tree=ggparent/gparent/parent&page=test
```

Notes:

- This assumes that a page and parent must not be exactly two chars long (you could specify an explicit or-list of all languages you have)
- Learn more about regex: https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Comment: I do have this as required validation point: for page name to be at least 3 characters long, hence two characters between slashes could only mean lang. 

There's one case I didn't mention, what if slash is at the end? Technically it shouldn't happen because I have a rewriteRule for that prior to this one, but just out of curiosity

Comment: Add a `\/?` just before `$`

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can try this regex:

```
^([a-z]{2}(?=\/|$))?(?:\/?(.+)\/)?(.*)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/uTLa5j/1)

---

This will match 3 groups: first the language (two characters), then the parents and the last group is last part of the URL (after `/`).

Comment: This fails on `en/test`, where the slash is part of the page